# Aggregation on time range

Tags: postgresql, time, aggregation

I have a data-set that contains date {yyyy/mm/dd} and time {h,m,s} and temperature {float} as an individual columns.

I want to aggregate temperature values for each day by average function.

The problem is that, I don't know how I can query the time attribute to say for example aggregate `{h,m, (0-5)s}` and `{h,m, (5-10)s}` and `{h,m, (10-15)s}` and ..., automatically.

Comment: Check out this: http://www.depesz.com/2010/10/22/grouping-data-into-time-ranges/

Comment: As I understand the should be contain data and time as a same column to use aforementioned approach. In my data-set date and time are placed in columns separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    day,
    to_char(date_trunc('minute', "time"), 'HH24:MI') as "minute",
    extract(second from "time")::integer / 5 as "range",
    avg(temperature) as average
from (
    select d::date as day, d::time as "time", random() * 100 as temperature
    from generate_series('2012-01-01', '2012-01-03', '1 second'::interval) s(d)
) d
group by 1, 2, 3
order by 1, 2, 3
;
```

If you want the average for all days:

```
select
    to_char(date_trunc('minute', "time"), 'HH24:MI') as "minute",
    extract(second from "time")::integer / 5 as "range",
    avg(temperature) as average
from (
    select d::time as "time", random() * 100 as temperature
    from generate_series('2012-01-01', '2012-01-03', '1 second'::interval) s(d)
) d
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
;
```

I think the important part for your question is to group by the integer result of the division of the seconds by the range size.

Comment: Dear Clodoaldo, For utilizing aforementioned codes should I have time and date in a single column?

Comment: @aliamidi It can be both in single as in two columns. The generate_series above generates a single column. Your query will use not the generate_series but your own table in instead.