# postgreSQL - Sum hours by unique ID and more

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to SUM the time by unique ID (meaning only one per ID). Here is a markup of some of the data. I need to GROUP BY f_name, l_name and area. I also need group count (unique count of id) and group participants (just a simple count of the ids).

```
+----+------+-------+-------+------+--+
| ID | Time | fname | lname | Area |  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+--+
|  1 | 3:30 | Jeff  | Chose | LA   |  |
|  1 | 3:30 | Jeff  | Chose | LA   |  |
|  1 | 3:30 | Jeff  | Chose | LA   |  |
|  2 | 4:00 | Jeff  | Chose | LA   |  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+--+
```

The data should look like:

```
+------+-------+-------+------+-------------+--------------------+
| Time | fname | lnam  | Area | Group Count | Group Participants |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------------+--------------------+
| 7:30 | Jeff  | Chose | LA   |           2 |                  4 |
|      |       |       |      |             |                    |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------------+--------------------+
```

BONUS: If you can convert 3:30 to 3.5

Comment: I dont see any SUM on your result. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/GUI4265)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT fname, lname, Area,
           COUNT(DISTINCT id) as "Group Count",
           COUNT(id) as "Group Participants", 
           SUM(DISTINCT "time"::time) as "Time"
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY fname, lname, Area, id 
)    
SELECT fname, lname, Area,
       SUM("Group Count") as "Group Count",
       SUM("Group Participants") as "Group Participants", 
       SUM("Time"::time) as "Time"
FROM cte
GROUP BY fname, lname, Area;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I knew I should have added more rows. I need to sum all the time for all people. I will edit the question and repost. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is aggregate time is very complex . You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008674/performing-aggregation-through-date-and-time-in-sql

Comment: Ok. I can do the converting part. I just need help with the aggregrate time with the group count and group participants that is grouped by fname, lname and area.

Comment: Almost. The issue with this is that the hours are adding up because they are different. If id 1 and id 2 had the same time value it wouldn't add. I tried that in the fiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Can you update the fiddle with some data and explain why you consider it a wrong result and what is your expected result?

Comment: I will work on a fiddle but I will try to explain first. What I am looking for is code that will SUM the time value for every unique ID number. So your example works but if ID 1 and ID 2 have the same value (say 3:00) it won't SUM them because of the DISTINCT. I will update with the fiddle soon.

Comment: What would be the expected result in that case?

Comment: It would be 7:00 (3:30 for ID 1 and 3:30 for ID 2).

Comment: Can you give me some background on what is this table about? Because I feel the design is wrong. I can try to solve as you request but I think would be better fix the db design instead of trying to solve using complicated queries

Comment: For start if you have 4 participants. Each one should have a different "ID" you need a primary key. And how is GROUP count 2 but participant 4?. A person cant participate multiple times.

Comment: Its a fictional table. I included the fields I thought would be required to complete what I wanted.

Comment: The table is about groups. So the group with the ID of 1 could happen today, and the group with ID 2 could happen tomorrow (So participants a person can participate many times). The individuals and the group workers all have ID's but its only the group ID that matters.

Comment: My problem is you `GROUP BY name` and you can have different people with same name

Comment: Right. Grouping by Worker ID would be better. I can work all that out. I just need to hours portion working.\

Comment: Check now. I use a subquery to separate the time from each group. I include the subquery result separated so you can see the previous step

Comment: I have to test before I know but the tallied result is exactly what I need.

Comment: MS Query doesn't like this code. I just realized that I didnt mention that I am using ODBC from Postgres to Excel using MS Query.

Comment: What you mean MS Query? Your tag is postgresql :(

Comment: Sorry. I think I need to collect all my information and post again.

Comment: You are lucky are new here. Because this wasnt an easy experience :/. Next time try to include a bigger example with all the logic you require

Comment: Just change `""` for `[]` for field names, and check what is the right data type to add time

Comment: I am getting a 'FROM missing' error. You did get it right, I am the one that cant get it to work. Thanks. I have upvoted your answer.